# DMO missing in XP

Tags: mp3, naudio, dmo

On my Win2008 dev machine, I'm making use of NAudio's DmoMp3FrameDecompressor. It makes use of the following DMO:

> MP3 Decoder DMO ({BBEEA841-0A63-4F52-A7AB-A9B3A84ED38A})

On an XP machine, playback is failing because this DMO is not present on the system. I'd like to know:

1. Where does this DMO come from?
2. Is it possible to install it in XP? The [naudio source code](https://naudio.svn.codeplex.com/svn/NAudio/Dmo/WindowsMediaMp3Decoder.cs) indicates that it should be possible.
3. Which Microsoft package includes it?
4. Is it possible to add it to my installer as a merge module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Where does this DMO come from?*

It seems to be on most versions of Windows from Vista onwards

*Is it possible to install it in XP? The naudio source code indicates that it should be possible.*

I don't think so. Why do you think the NAudio source code indicates this? On XP you should use the ACM MP3 decoder,

*Which Microsoft package includes it?*

None that I know of. If you're on Windows Server, make sure the desktop experience is installed

*Is it possible to add it to my installer as a merge module?*

Don't think so I am afraid. There tend to be strict licensing conditions about redistributing MP3 decoders.

Comment: From the horse's mouth, so to speak. Cheers Mark.